# Specify design time binding context in a GridTemplateColumn

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project. In my xaml page, order to avoid "Cannot resolve property 'xxx'" warning, I've set a design-time data context.
In this page I have a SfDataGrid object.

In the following code snippet, the text property of the custom entry is binding to the Quantity field of a `Part` item. The Parts object is an `ObservableCollection<Part>`.

```
<xForms:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Margin="0"
                   ScrollingMode="PixelLine"  
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
  <xForms:SfDataGrid.Columns>
      <xForms:GridTextColumn MappingName="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" 
                             HeaderTextAlignment="Start" ColumnSizer="Star"
                             TextAlignment="Start" Padding="5,0,5,0"/>
      <!--#region Quantity column -->                               
      <xForms:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
                                 HeaderTextAlignment="Center" 
                                 ColumnSizer="Auto" Padding="0" >
          <xForms:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <controls:CustomEntry Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                              Converter={StaticResource NullableDouble}}" 
                                        Keyboard="Numeric" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="End"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </xForms:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </xForms:GridTemplateColumn>
      <!--#endregion -->
  </xForms:SfDataGrid.Columns>
</xForms:SfDataGrid>
```

The warning is displayed under the Quantity word in `Text={Binding Quantity, Mode...`

What should I do to avoid the warning for the binding used in the cell templates?

Should I add a `BindingContext="{d:DesignInstance models:Part}"`, or `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:Part}"` on each field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Crusty Applesniffer,

Thanks for using Syncfusion Product.

We have checked your query with following details.
By using SfDataGrid have created the GridTemplateClolumn and added CustomEntry as DataTemplate in XAML page

- Text property of this custom entry is binding to the double type
  property named as OrderId
- We have set this Text property binding
- Mode as TwoWay, And we have written the converter for this property.
- And we have added the Xaml 
  Complilation([XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]) Tag in .cs of the XAML 
  class file.

But unfortunately, We are unable to reproduce the “Cannot resolve property 'xxx'" warning” from our side, So Kindly provide More details in order to reproduce the issue.

- Have you enabled any Style Cop or FxCop rule set in your application
  ? If yes, Mention  those rule set details.
- Type of property you have used to bind the Custom Entry Text Property.
- SfDataGrid product version that you are currently using.
- If possible kindly provide us the Issue replicating sample or modify the attached sample to replicate the issue.
  We have prepared the sample as per your requirement, Do check and let us know Is there anything needs to add more to reproduce “Cannot resolve property 'xxx'" warning” issue.

Sample Link :  http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DataGrid-1806700714

Regards,
Vigneshkumar R

Comment: You were right, "Cannot resolve property" was notified by Resharper (from JetBrain).
 I'll see this with JetBrain support.
Thank you